# How to display recursive geometric image in browser with infinite zooming?

Tags: browser, images, svg, recursive, fractal

### Context

Suppose one has a [pentagonal tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_tiling) where each plane is also made up of a pentagonal tiling (if that is not possible, assume cubic). Suppose each parent is `x` times larger than its child. Then one has a fractal tiling where one can zoom in indefinitely whilst seeing new/other fractal tilings. Assume the largest image is a single tile.

### Question

How could one display such a tile in a webbrowser whilst allowing the user to smoothly zoom in and out of the tiling indefinitely?

### Initial approach

First I thought of making a vector image, like a `.svg`, `.pdf` or `.eps`, however, those seem to require a fixed set of coordinates for the lines, and since it is a fractal pattern, there are infinite coordinates for infinite zooming. Also, it would require quite a bit of bandwidth to assume a user would only zoom in 1000 times before moving on to doing something else. This is because the number of coordinates per layer/zoom level grows exponentially. So I thought it would be better to run the function that generates the coordinates in the browser.

However, I am not yet familiar with such in-browser visualisation techniques, and was wondering whether there are some technologies/open source packages available that support this interaction in the browser.